# Are there any alternatives to pulling a large dataset from a SQL database besides using odbc, RODBC, etc?

Tags: r

I have an 80,000,000 table that I am trying to pull into R using ODBC. In general, this task takes around 30 minutes when I run it in SQL Server.

However, I have a simple query with one conditional statement that produces the following error.

```
> interaction_detail_dat = get_sql_data(driver = "SQL Server",
+                                       server = "sdl02-vm14",
+                                       query_text = which_query) %>% as.data.table()
get_sql_data  -  eror  -  Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n, ...): nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2525: 01000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionWrite (send()).
```

Are there any other alternatives to pulling data from SQL for pulling data besides odbc, RODBC, etc?

Comment: We use [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-and-export-bulk-data-by-using-the-bcp-utility-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) from windows to do bulk operations. You can use the `system2` command to call bcp e.g. `system2("bcp", args=c("-d", data_base_arg))`. It's a bit tricky to get to grips with but is very efficient